# jquery get the data-id of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table created from jQuery:

```
$('#btniLoad').click(function(){
var gradelevel = $('#ylvl').val();

$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:"<?php echo site_url('enrollment/searchTeacher');?>",
dataType:'json',
data:{q:gradelevel},
success: function(data){

  if(!data.teacherinfo[0])
  {
    var table = "There's no teacher registered yet";

  }
  else
  {
    var table = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
    table += "<thead><th>Teacher's Name</th></thead><tbody>";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.teacherinfo.length;i++)
    {
      table += "<tr><td><a href='#teachermodal' data-toggle='modal' role='button' id='teachview' data-id='"
      +data.teacherinfo[i].teacherid+"'>"
      +data.teacherinfo[i].FirstName+', '+data.teacherinfo[i].MiddleName+', '
      +data.teacherinfo[i].LastName+"</a></td></tr>";
    }
    table += "</tbody></table>";
  }

    $('#teacherTable').empty();
    $('#teacherTable').append(table);
},
});
});
```

I want to display in the console log the data-id that is in the href to check if it passes the id correctly but I don't get any result from the console log....
 This is the click event for the anchor tag:

```
$(function(){
$('#teachview').click(function(){
var teachid = $(this).attr("data-id");
console.log(teachid);
});
});
```

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','#teachview',function(){` instead of `$('#teachview').click(function(){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: also ***ID should be unique*** if you are generating element dynamically use class instead

Comment: i think you need to do a loop `$('.teachview').each(function(){})` since teachview can be multiple instance, add a class instead of ID

Comment: @guradio lol same point of view

Comment: do i need to put the loop inside the click event?

Comment: I tried @guradio suggestion and it solved my problem. Thanks for the help much appreciated....

Comment: i will put it as answer and you can tick it so that this question will be answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(document).on('click','#teachview',function(){` instead of `$('#teachview').click(function(){`

also ***ID should be unique*** use ***class instead***

Comment: np im glad it helped happy coding mate